# Where in Eclipse can I find my project's workspace path

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-mars

I already know about switching workspaces.. but it's not entirely clear what the exact workspace path is?

I actually used this url as a reference:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/get-eclipse-current-workspace-path/

But if you do the switch workspace trick, to try and get the correct workspace? If you have other Eclipse projects open, your "Selection of the other workspace option" can get corrupted..

i.e. It may show the path to one of your other open Eclipse workspaces..

Therefore, that is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the properties of your project... 
Then to the Resource/Linked Resources:

http://ispecsoft.com/Taught1/post/2016/05/26/How-to-find-Eclipse-Project-workspace-location.aspx

[image: Workspace and Project Paths]

Comment: someone downvoted this.. I would like to know why? or was it Andy...? :)